# Moment of undefined vs moment of null

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I wonder why

```
> moment(undefined).isBefore()
true
```

but

```
> moment(null).isBefore()
false
```

Is there any rational explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`moment(undefined)` is equivalent to `moment()`, which assumes the initial state to be the current date/time.

`moment(null)`, on the other hand, is not a thing. It is not valid (at least not in the version I'm playing with), and has undocumented results.

Of course, you can [read the source code](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/25cc720fbaab7323a1016cd0beb6a36e349c41be/src/lib/moment/compare.js#L17), and find that `isBefore` doesn't check for `undefined` either. In other words, momentjs is not expecting itself to be used this way, twice.

Comment: I found out that the behavior is _even more_ interesting. Try running it with `undefined` multiple times with short interval and you'll see that _sometimes_ it returns `true` and most of the times `false`.

Comment: You may see that it is `true` for a short period of time before it becomes `false` again. This is due to `moment(undefined)` being the current timestamp. Run `setInterval(function (){console.log(moment(undefined).isBefore());}, 0);` to go down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Interesting find.  I think this is just because it takes a few nanoseconds to create a `moment` object and occasionally two consecutive instantiations will be on either side of a millisecond boundary.  The same results can be obtained with `setInterval(function (){console.log(moment().isSame(moment()));}, 0);`, but interestingly not with `setInterval(function (){console.log(new Date().getTime() === new Date().getTime());}, 0);`

Comment: Actually, I just got the same results with the `Date` example.  It just takes a lot more cycles to hit them.  I wrote this up here: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2659